# OverflowError: int too large to convert to float even with "Decimal" - Python

Tags: python

This question got already an answer on stackoverflow and the recommended solution was to use "Decimal" form the module math

But Decimal didn't work ->

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math

def pow_opt(x:int, n:int)-> int:
    result = 1
    while Decimal(math.pow(x,n)):
        if (n%2 == 0):
            x = x**2
            n = n/2
        else:
            result = result*x
            n = n-1
print(pow_opt(4,2))
```

And the following error is returned :

[click to see error]

[image: 1]

Comment: You're not doing any of the math with the `Decimal` object.

Comment: i tested using the `Decimal` object but then i get a decimal overflow

Comment: but how I fix this then ?

Comment: To start, `math.pow(x,n)` is only falsey under certain conditions. Is there not a much simpler test you can do?

Answer (score 2):

You hardly need any `Decimal` for that. Your implementation is incorrect. When it has been corrected (see code below) it works with integers:

```py
def pow_opt(x:int, n:int)-> int:
    result = 1
    while n:
        if (n%2 == 0):
            x = x**2
            n = n/2
        else:
            result = result*x
            n = n-1
    return result
```